# Flash AS3 fullscreen problem: screen reverts to normal mode

Tags: actionscript-3, fullscreen

I've got a fullscreen button which, when clicked, works. However, after a few seconds, Flash automatically exits full-screen mode and reverts to normal mode. I'm running this in the browser. I tried stripping all the code in the fullScreen event handler down to this (I removed toggling between displayStates):

```
    private function fullScreenHandler( event:MouseEvent ):void
    {           
        stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;

    }
```

It's still happening.  Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Voted down? If you google 'fullscreen reverts' or anything else you can think of, you come up with nothing that helps. I am describing unpredictable behavior. It's the kind of thing where someone will come across it and say, "Oh yeah this happened to me once. Here's what it was."

Comment: Voted up, don't understood why the question was voted down!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it exit fullscreen after the same amount of time every time? It could be something silly like the computer going to sleep then. I've never experienced flash player standalone exiting fullscreen in such a case but I could imagine because its in a browser that changes things.

So I'd suggest to try running it from the flash player as opposed to the browser if you can. This should tell you if it is something wrong with your app or the browser.

On the same note try it on different browsers. Since I imagine its fairly portable you should also consider trying it on different physical computers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, guys.   It doesn't exit fullscreen after the same amount of time, and it isn't the computer going to sleep. It is a bug in Firefox 4 for the mac. I tried it with Safari and with Google Chrome, and it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hang function on full screen exiting, insert some code which will throw an exception (e.g. try to call some method of a null, it's the simpliest way in Haxe/Flash) and see stack trace of exception. You'll see what causes exit from full-screen.